# how to search a particular string in a text file in c

Tags: c, string, text-files, file-handling

I need to find a particular string from the contents of a text file. The user inputs the string they're looking for and the program searches through the opened text file to find that string. Is that possible using C?

This is the basic code that should be expanded with the functionality:

```
void exam()
{
char name[50], rollno[50];
FILE *search;
printf("\t\t________________________________");
printf("\n\n\t\t\tPortal Examination");
printf("\n\t\t_______________________________");
printf("\n\tEnter Name : ");
scanf("%s", name);
search = fopen("Students.txt", "r");
}
```

Comment: Read (parts of) the file into memory, then use standard string function [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) to search the string (in a loop).

Comment: OK, here we go... 'I have searched this site and many others and none has answered my question' - please post the Google search string you used and a couple of the links that you found.

Comment: @Magisch waiting was a shield plan to stave off any meta attacks for being 'unhelpful and hostile'.

Comment: @MartinJames Anyways, I've hammered this into shape a little, and maybe someone feels inclined to answer it (again) or flag it as appropiate dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect a particular string in a file using C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295321/how-to-detect-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-c-program)

Comment: @MartinJames It is unfortunate that the accepted answer to that question was written by someone who doesn't seem to know about repetition structures in procedural/imperative programming languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C strings from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079828/c-strings-from-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

> Read (parts of) the file into memory, then use standard string
>   function [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) to search the
>   string (in a loop). – pmg

```
…
    search = fopen("Students.txt", "r");
    if (!search) { perror("Students.txt"); return; }
    char line[4095+1];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, search))
        if (strstr(line, name)) printf("%s", line);
    fclose(search);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure. In fact, this is an exact example I produced for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565400/best-approach-to-continuously-scan-for-a-string-in-a-streaming-buffer):

```
void find_match(FILE *input_file, char const *needle, size_t needle_size) {
    char input_array[needle_size];
    size_t sz = fread(input_array, 1, needle_size, input_file);
    if (sz != needle_size) {
        // No matches possible
        return;
    }

    setvbuf(input_file, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
    unsigned long long pos = 0;
    for (;;) {
        size_t cursor = pos % needle_size;
        int tail_compare = memcmp(input_array, needle + needle_size - cursor, cursor),
            head_compare = memcmp(input_array + cursor, needle, needle_size - cursor);
        if (head_compare == 0 && tail_compare == 0) {
            printf("Match found at offset %llu\n", pos);
        }
        int c = fgetc(input_file);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        input_array[cursor] = c;
        pos++;
    }
}
```